# Android WorkManager use cases

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I am reading about WorkManager (https://developer.android.com/guide/background). What confuses me are the 2 conflicting statements. It says WorkManager should be used:

1. For tasks that **should be executed immediately** and need continued processing
2. For tasks that **can run at any time in the future** can be and deferred

Can someone explain this and show me 2 simple examples with the code of WorkManger that does statement number1 and statement number2 situations. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorkManager` is basically to offload work from your Process/Activity to dedicated worker meaning your app doesn't need to be active for WorkManager to do your work.

The above mentioned both statements makes sense, I won't be writing code but i'll mention use cases supporting two statements.

**Statement1** says tasks which should be executed immediately and need continued processing, it means you can schedule any task right away and will be long running, for instance consider you are uploading some images on click of a button, so you will start the UploadWorker as soon as user clicks upload(instantly) and even if user kills your App, upload should still happen which will be taken care by WorkManager.

**Statement2** says  tasks that can run at any time in the future can be and deferred, it means you can schedule some work in future point of time and WorkManager will run it at your desired time. A typical example would be backups, you want to back up user data every day at morning, then you can create a BackUpWorker and ask WorkManager to run it at a future time periodically.

Comment: Isn't the second case you mentioned ideal for using AlarmManager?

Comment: WorkManager is modern day library which uses multiple framework specific schedulers to do the work based on best suitable option, device, battery, OS version etc, , one of them is Alarm Manager

Comment: Ok one more question I need to ask you. "For tasks that can run at any time in the future can be and deferred". Do we achieve this in code with same call to workmanager as in the first case but we only add set of constraints (for example "must be connected to wifi) and this makes the request defferable. Is that what they mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly, when all constraints are met, you work is scheduled and it is not guaranteed to execute at the exact time, but depends on system constraints also

Comment: OK cool. I would also like to say that I did some reading since we start talk and I think that workManager still doesn't include AlarmManager in itself. They are divided and called independently one of another. In some cases we can use them both in combination but it doesn't mean workManager library contains AlarmManaer in itself I guess...

Comment: All in all thank you for answer, you halped me